# MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: azure, powershell

[image]I'm following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp to deploy my bot created previously
However when i run this command :

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win-x86 --self-contained
```

it return this error

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current 
working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you you are deploying a bot that targets the **.NET Core 3.1 SDK** and you are deploying to a center that can't build .NET Core 3.1 apps using Kudu, use this work around to prepare and zip up your bot files; otherwise, you can use the steps in the next sections.

As the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=Python#5-prepare-your-code-for-deployment) said, when you can't build .net core 3.1 app using kudu then you use `dotnet publish` to prepare.

However, the snapshot you provided is showing that **you are using python**, which **you do not need to prepare your project files before deploying a Python bot**. Follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=Python#52-zip-up-the-code-directory-manually) and zip up the code directory manually.

[image]